# Using multiple stacks in MIPS assembly

Tags: sorting, stack, mips, mars-simulator, radix

I have to create a radixsort in MIPS assembly, which requires multiple stacks for the digits 0-9 and I'm not sure what's a good way to do that, since there is only one stack pointer.

I tried to just use `$t0`-`$t9` as stacks but it seems like that isn't possible and I would imagine that there is better solution anyway, but unfortunately I couldn't find much information about multiple stacks in MIPS assembly.

Comment: Nothing prevents you to have multiple stacks (each stack's top pointed by one register), though I don't think it would be a good idea.

Comment: Also from your task it seems you don't want N stacks, you want N bins each one holding the number of elements of each type seen in the list to sort. So, an array of N words should suffice.

Comment: A good sorting algorithm won't require multiple stacks

Comment: I found a different solution now by sorting the digits in the stack when I add them. Originally I thought that a radixsort by definition has to put the digits in different stacks but apparently that's not the case.